# Prove $T$ is diagonalisable if $T^*=\alpha T$ for some $\alpha\in\mathbb{C}$

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, inner-products, diagonalization, adjoint-operators

**Question**

Let $V$ be a finite-dimensional vector space over $\mathbb{C}$. Let $T:V\to V$ be a linear map, and $T^*$ its adjoint.

If $T^*=\alpha T$ for some $\alpha\in\mathbb{C}$ show that $T$ is diagonalisable.

**My attempt**

For all $v,w\in V$ we have $\langle v, T(w) \rangle = \langle T^*(v), w \rangle = \langle \alpha T(v), w \rangle = \bar{\alpha} \langle T(v), w \rangle = \bar{\alpha} \langle v, T^*(w) \rangle = \bar{\alpha}\alpha \langle v, T(w) \rangle$

So by non-degeneracy, $T=|\alpha|^2 T$.

But how do I find a basis of eigenvectors of $T$?

Comment: If $\alpha=-1$ then $T$ is skew-hermitian and, thus; diagonalizible. Otherwise $(\alpha+1)T=T+T^*$ is hermitian and therefore diagonalizible.

Comment: @Levent How does showing $T+T^*$ diagonalisable prove that $T$ is diagonalisable? It is $T$ we are after

Comment: But $T+T^*=(\alpha+1)T$ so if the LHS is diagonalizible then so is RHS.

Comment: @Levent Okay I see, thanks. But if $(\alpha + 1)T$ is diagonalisable how does that imply that $T$ is?

Comment: Diagonalize $(\alpha+1)T$ and then divide by $\alpha+1)$.

Answer (score 1):

Well if you know the spectral theorem then it follows by just one sentence:-

$TT^{*}=\alpha T^{2}=T^{*}T$ . Thus $T$ is normal and hence unitarily diagonalizable.

Answer (score 0):

If $\vert\alpha\vert^2\neq 1$, then $T=0$ and $T$ is diagonalizable.
If $\vert\alpha\vert^2=1 $, one may write $\alpha=\dfrac{u}{\bar{u}}$ with $u\neq 0$.

Then $(uT)^*=(uT)$. Since $uT$ is self adjoint, it is diagonalizable, and therefore, so is $T$.

Comment: How does the last therefore follow?

Comment: @jet Is diagonalizability affected by multiplication by a scalar?